# Fix div to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project I want to fix a div element to a certain position on the **screen.** Not the window, the screen. So if the browser is resized the div stays put and if the browser is moved the div stays put. Possible?

Here is my basic html page that contains just a dot at the center of the screen.

```css
#dot {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #000;
    position:relative;
    left: -4px;
    top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
    <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

I know I can use `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` and then do some math to ensure the position is set to give the illusion of a fixed element, however that would require polling the window position every millisecond to detect when the browser is moved (which is probably pretty heavy and rare anyways). The plan is to do this with much more than just a dot...

Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: You can't do that other than how you already know

Comment: Which is why I want to add it to my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `requestAnimationFrame`, which is better for this sort of tasks than `setInterval`, to keep an eye on `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` and also to move (animate) the point div if those numbers change:

```
var x = window.screenX,
    y = window.screenY;

function moveDot() {
    if(x !== window.screenX || y !== window.screenY)
        console.log('move dot');

    x = window.screenX;
    y = window.screenY;
}

(function animloop(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    moveDot();
})();
```

[Here's the Can I Use link for requestAnimationFrame](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: Well, it's a little laggy. Kinda wobbles around, not as clean as I would have wanted... hmmm.

Comment: Yep, It doesn't gets called every millisecond. I don't know if you can use an animation to put things back into place, but I think that can help you because the implementation may vary between browsers, I'm using Chrome in a macbook and here the `screenX` and `screenY` properties change **when I stop moving the browser**, they don't change for every pixel moved, so the dot won't move smoothly in this case.

Comment: Maybe the issue lies in the fact that after changing the position it isn't shown until the next frame?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` interval is 60fps (every 16ms aprox), if you want to reduce that time the only option left would be `setInterval` .

Answer (score 2):

Since `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` are only accessible in JS, there is really no way to do this other than polling the variables and changing the css using javascript.